# How to test if instance's method is called with "self" when mocking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I'm using `unittest.mock`, this wonderful library. However I was surprised by an unexpected behavior, and I don't see an obvious solution. I'm  using it for my unit tests and it is vital to understand perfectly how it behaves to have useful tests.

I know the code below in `show_bar` is broken, it is calling a classmethod instead of the instance method. However, all my `mock` **unittests** are passing :

*Code containing a bug*:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        return "bar"

    def show_bar(self):
        return Foo.bar()
```

*Expected usage:*

```
foo = Foo()
assert foo.show_bar() == "bar"
# => throw exception: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

*Unittest tries unsuccessfully to catch this error with `mock`:*

```
from unittest.mock import patch
with patch.object(Foo, 'bar', return_value="bar") as mock:
    foo = Foo()
    assert foo.show_bar() == "bar"
mock.assert_called_once()
# => no errors
```

Ideally, I would like to **assert** that `bar` is called with `self.bar()` and NOT `Foo.bar()` ; which is wrong. Unfortunately, using `mock.assert_called_with()` does not take in account the `self` nor `cls` parameter, so I'm a bit confused.

*EDIT*: Trying to clarify. I'm looking for best practices to use the library `unittest.mock` when we need to patch an object's method. It seems not clear to me how to patch it, currently I have no way to assert if it's calling `self.bar` or `Foo.bar`.

Comment: Don't mock anything, just call `f = Foo(); f.bar()` in your test code. With the broken implementation it will raise a `TypeError`, making the test fail.

Comment: Also and FWIW, this has nothing to do with `classmethod` - in your example `Foo.bar` is an unbound instance method.

Comment: Sorry, the code is oversimplified and I *need* to use mock because the actual code of the method is not callable without mocking its return value. Also, when `show_bar` developer calls `Foo.bar()`, I was assuming `Foo.bar` is either a classmethod or a staticmethod. It seems a reasonable statement?

Comment: Sorry, not enough context to make an informed judgement here... wrt/ the class or static method part I just wanted to make clear that `Foo.bar` was neither in you current implementation and that looking it up on the class would not make it one either. Possibly something got lost in translation ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you'd need to mock the method to test that it does not raise a TypeError when called but anyway... Someone else might explain how to solve this using `unittest.mock`, in the meantime you can just skip `unittest.mock` and mock `Foo.bar` by yourself:

```
 callargs = dict()  
 def mock_bar(self):
     callargs["self"] = self
     return "bar"

 foobar = Foo.__dict__["bar"] 
 Foo.bar = mock_bar
 try: 
     foo = Foo()
     assert foo.show_bar() == "bar"
     assert "self" in callargs
     assert callargs["self"] is foo
 finally:
     Foo.bar = foobar
```

Comment: Actually I'm not trying to fix my issue which is trivial, neither mocking "manually" my class, I'm only looking for using `unittest.mock` correctly to replace methods calls in unittesting context. Thanks for trying to help though!